# Sending Files from PC to Android Phones via bluetooth

Tags: java, android

I want to create an application that sends data from PC to android phones via bluetooth.
Im referring the below mentioned link for the same

http://www.substanceofcode.com/2008/06/20/sending-files-to-mobile-phone-using-bluetooth-and-obex/#comment-340224895

i wonder if comments like "it works on some devices" are based on mobile OS? i tried it on galaxy ace and i received the following exception: Failed to connect; [10064] A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.
But when i tried in on nokia 6220c, it works fine. so is this about android/symbian, if it is what should i change to make it work on android phone?

The application works only for java based phones...what changes should i make it work on android phone?

Comment: You need to provide code at least and specify your question.

Answer (score 0):

This project uses a Bluetooth profile called [OBEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBEX)

Not all phones will implement this profile, thus that program will not work with phones that don't implement it. Furthermore, it requires a lot of work to implement a custom profile on Android so it is usually better to find a different way of transferring files.